# How do I retrieve one item from each group in a nested set

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data

I have three tables for matching products to categories:

1. categories,
2. products, (which can actually ignore)
3. categories_products which is many-to-many reference table

The categories table is a nested set and simplified it looks like:

```
categories:
id, parent_id, name,                 level
1,  null,      Electronics,          1
2,  1,         Kitchen Appliances,   2
3,  1,         Personal Electronics, 2
5,  2,         Coffee Makers,        3
6,  2,         Juicers,              3
7,  3,         MP3 Players,          3
8,  3,         Mobile Phones,        3
....
1000,
```

categories_products is simply

```
categories_products
id, category_id, product_id
1,  5,           42
2,  5,           45
3,  6,           63
4,  7,           76
5,  7,           32
...
8000,
```

**Note: All products are linked at the 3rd level of the category tree**

Now what I'd like is a query that can return me 1 (random) product for every 2nd level category. (either grouped by the 1st level category or I could just make separate queries passing in the 1st level id.)

So in the example above I would get 1 item from Kitchen Applicances, which means one random item from either category 5 or 6, and 1 item from Personal Electroincs, which means one item from category 7.

This is way beyond my sql level so looking for any help possible.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not look like a nested set model, this looks like an adjacency  model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query and join it hen with `products` table. The line  with `ROW_NUMBER` orders products random inside a category so then you just select first one - (`rn=1`).

```
SELECT product_id,
       category_id,
       category_name 
FROM
( select product_id,
         c2.id category_id,
         c2.name category_name,
         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY c2.id ORDER BY random()) as rn
  FROM categories_products cp
  JOIN categories c3 ON (cp.category_id=c3.id)
  JOIN categories c2 ON (c3.parent_id=c2.id) 
) T 
WHERE rn =1
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a162/4)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You actually only need the `categories` table. You are looking to extract 1 row from each group of rows with same `parent_id` where `level = 3` (so that each category with `level = 2` gets 1 row returned.Using a window function does the trick:

```
SELECT id, parent_id, name, level
FROM (
  SELECT id, parent_id, name, level,
         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY random()) AS rn
  FROM categories
  WHERE level = 3) sub
WHERE rn = 1;
```